# AWS Lambda function in Java - Getting error "errorMessage": "Class not found: lambda.PocLambdaHandler",

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am creating a stack from AWS-CDK, which in-turn creates a cloudformation template, and creates Lambda resources.

The problem I'm facing is the above error.

My project structure is:

```
main-project
 - lambda\PocLambdaHandler.java
 - src\main\java\com\myorg
  - JavaPocApp.java
  - JavaPocStack.java
```

In my **JavaPocStack.java** I'm defining a function as:

```
final Function FunctionPOC = Function.Builder.create(this, "POCHandlerStack")
        .runtime(Runtime.JAVA_8) 
        .code(Code.fromAsset("lambda"))
        .handler("lambda.PocLambdaHandler")
        .build();
```

Then, I'm doing an `mvn clean package` and then `cdk deploy`, all these work fine and the stack gets deployed and resources get created, problem is when I run a test on the lambda, it fails with above error.

I have tried making changes as per this: 'https://github.com/webdevwilson/aws-lambda-maven-cdk/blob/master/infra/src/cdk/Stack.java' and 'https://github.com/aws-samples/cdk-lambda-packaging-java/blob/main/infrastructure/src/main/java/com/myorg/InfrastructureStack.java', still the issue persists.

It however works if I create a **hello.js** under `\lambda` folder, change the run time to **NODEJS_14_X** and call `.handler("hello.handler")`.

I'm not sure what is wrong with this when I use it to point to `PocLambdaHandler.java` under `\lambda`, can someone please help me?
I've also go through multiple stackoverflow solutions, but to no avail!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Another problem with this I've seen is when I create the mvn package, and open the .jar under /target, I do not see the /lambda/PocLambdaHandler.java file anywhere.
My POM structure (part):
 ```<groupId>com.myorg</groupId> 
<artifactId>venky-java-poc</artifactId> <version>0.1</version>```

Comment: Have you followed the instructions in https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/packaging-and-deploying-aws-lambda-functions-written-in-java-with-aws-cloud-development-kit/? Your lambda handler is not correct. It should be com.myorg.JavaPocApp. It should be the fully qualified name of your class.

Comment: @kgiannakakis, thanks for your quick response. Yes, I have looked at that too, but still the same issue.
I believe the issue is with the mvn packaging, it, for some reason, is not including the /lambda folder nor the PocLambdaHandler.java file. Any help here is much appreciated.